# PHP-Display single value outside the loop (on Laravel F/W)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I am trying to display the status of the store on the side of the dropdown box, which shows if the store is open or closed. The status inside the dropdown box is correct but the one next to the dropdown is not correct. The correct one value comes from the loop and I want that value to be shown outside the loop. The loop i am using is foreach. Please see the image attached to get the better understanding. I get the value but the last value stored, I want the first value of that row.

I tried to approach many ways to solve this, but no luck so far.

[image]

My Code is:-

```
<?php   

                 date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
                 $datetime = new \DateTime();

                 $listItem = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');

                 $curDay = date('l');

                 $status = array( "Now Open" ,"Closed",  "Opening Soon",  "Closing Soon", "Open 24 hours", "  ");


                  $times =  array(
                    1 => array('day' => 'Monday', 'open' => $oMon, 'close' => $cMon),
                    2 => array('day' => 'Tuesday', 'open' => $oTue, 'close' => $cTue),
                    3 => array('day' => 'Wednesday', 'open' => $oWed, 'close' => $cWed),
                    4 => array('day' => 'Thursday', 'open' => $oThur, 'close' => $cThur),
                    5 => array('day' => 'Friday', 'open' => $oFri, 'close' => $cFri),
                    6 => array('day' => 'Saturday','open' => $oSat, 'close' => $cSat),
                    7 => array('day' => 'Sunday', 'open' => $oSun, 'close' => $cSun));

                    $html= "" ;
                    $html .=  "<table class='table table-striped'  border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='15'>";

  $i = 1;



$cd = $datetime->format('N'); 

$timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());


// Create an array of day numbers that start with current day and loops around
//$day_order = array_merge(range($cd, 7), range(1, $cd-1));

$day_order = range($cd, 7);
if ($cd != 1) {
    $day_order = array_merge($day_order, range(1, $cd-1));
}



 foreach ($day_order as $daynum): {
    $oc = $times[$daynum];
    $openingTime = $oc['open'];
    $closingTime = $oc['close'];
    $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
    $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
    if ($cd == $daynum) {
        if ($openingTime === null && $closingTime === null) {
            $s = $status[4];
        }
        elseif ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
            $s = $status[1];
        }
        elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
            $s = $status[2];
        }
        elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
            $s = $status[3];
        } else {
            $s = $status[0];
        }
    } else {
        $s = " ";
    }





    $html .=  "<tr>";
    $html .=  "<td  class='span2'>". $oc['day']."</td>";
   // echo  "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
    $html .=  "<td>".$openingTime."     ".$closingTime."</td>";
   // echo  "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
    $html .=  "<td  class='span2'>".$s."</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";



}
      $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));





  endforeach;
  $html .=  "</table>";
  echo $html;






   ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using laravel?

Comment: I am using this code on the laravel. As I also tried using PHP reset, next, previous syntax and its not working here

Comment: I believe that your question is very broad and unclear. Display a single value outside a loop is like asking someone to guess the color of your underwear. Additionally, you need to provide short snippets of your code, just the part that isn't working.

Final piece of advice: you really need to work on your code elegance. Your code needs to be precise, self-explanatory and, well, beautiful. The code provided is none of the above...

Answer (score 0):

Hey  Theodore Messinezis, I have solve this code... it was so simple....

I just had to add this

```
 $st = ""; // <- I added the declaration here
foreach ($day_order as $daynum): {

...
...
.

}
$st .= $s;//  <- I add this line inside the loop to get value outside the array

 endforeach;

echo $.st;  <- Output
```

Comment: Theodore Messinezis, I am not a good coder and neither those skills to write them efficiently, but I am learning.